# maven create generated-test-sources before compiling tests

Tags: java, maven, code-generation, pom.xml

I have created a library that generates test source code based on an annotation found in the test code.

I have a second project that references from the test code

- the annotation from the library and
- the to-be-generated classes.

The issue is that the compilation phase is failing because the classes haven't any chance to be generated before compiling the tests.

In what way I can fix this issue?

**Update**
My plugins section:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-resource</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/test-annotations</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

The library that generates code is using an annotation processor that searches the client code for a particular annotation before generating source code. From what I know, the annotation processing is done at compile time, after the maven phase `generate-test-sources`.
I am starting to understand what is happening but I still cannot find a solution to this problem.

Now I am looking also at other code generation projects (for example `jaxb2-maven-plugin` for generating java classes from xml schemas) that do not use annotation processing like I do. Maybe it is a better idea to write a maven plugin after all...

Comment: Why are you generating main source code based off annotation present in test code? Could you expand a bit on your requirement?

Comment: It is generating test source code, not main source code. The library is looking for the schema.sql file in the test/resources folder and it is generating some Builder classes. These classes are meant to be used only in tests

Comment: If in your second project, you're binding the plugin generating the test resources in the `generate-test-resources` phase, and those test resources are added to the test classpath (either via the plugin or via [`build-helper:add-test-resource`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-test-resource-mojo.html) mojo, they should be picked up. Can you post a sample POM demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I tried to configure `build-helper-maven-plugin` by adding `target/generated-test-sources/annotations`, but still does not work. My tests fail to compile because the `generated-test-sources` do not exists. If I eliminate the usage of generated code from my tests, then compilation succeeds and code gets generated under `generated-test-sources`

Comment: Oh sorry I meant `add-test-source` (not resource) and phase `generate-test-sources` (not resources) in the comment above, since you're generating sources.

Comment: I have changed the goal to `add-test-source`. However the compilation still fails because there is nothing generated in `target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations` at the moment when the goal starts. Now I am starting to understand why: the library that generates code is using annotation processor and it searches for a particular annotation in the client source code. But the annotation processing happens at compile time